# Difference between this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() and Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() methods in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I know Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() is used to execute some piece of code in the UI thread.Recently I noticed that there is another way to get the Dispatcher instance by using 'Deployment' class. I would like to know

Is there any diffrence between the invokation of **this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()** and **Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()** functions ?, and

when should I use **this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()** and  **Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()** ?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer: They are the same in Silverlight, so use the shorter one (if available in the context of your code).**

`this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` ensures it is run on the thread that the control in question is running under.

`Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` ensures it is run on the main UI thread.

The two are always the same in Silverlight (and usually the same in WPF, unless you have created extra UI threads).

Use `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` unless your current context does not have a dispatcher, then use the global one instead.

Comment: Under what circumstances are they not the same?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Dispatcher.Current retrieves the dispatch object associated with the thread that is executing the code.  So they are not the same when called on different threads.

Comment: @Will: Did you mean Deployment.Current or Dispatcher.Current?

Comment: @wizzardz: Dispatcher.  I don't know about the behavior of Deployment.Current.

Comment: @Will:  The `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher` is always associated with the UI Thread in Silverlight.  There is no `Dispatcher.Current` in Silverlight.  A `DependencyObject` `Dispatcher` property also always returns a `Dispatcher` associated with the UI thread.  So I'm trying to imagine a scenario where there is a difference.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Just realised it was Silverlight only question. Yes they are always the same as you can't create extra UI threads in Silverlight. I will amend the answer